# how can i restore view to default in eclipse? i have tried all option but still facing this problem

Tags: eclipse

I have tried to restore default option in preferences ->Appearance and in Editor -> Text Editor. but still facing this problem.
whenever i move my cursor on a class object the background is black and can't see anything:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's the ***Information background color*** which can be changed or reset in:

*Window > **Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts: Basic > Information background color***